# Alfresco restart webscript after read timeout error

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

In an alfresco custom webscript, I have a read timeout error, afterwards the alfresco restarts the webscript.

Is possible disable this behaviour?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart the webscript" ? Can you show us your code ?